# Show and Hide loading ring in list view uwp

Tags: xaml, listview, binding, uwp

In my `UWP` project I have dynamic loaded list view and I want to show loading ring when next element is loading. 
In `XAML` I try doing something like:

```
    <Page
    x:Class="News.NewsDetailsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:News"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:MyConverter="using:News.BitmapConverter"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Black">
    <!--<ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRingLoad" Visibility="Collapsed"/>-->
    <ScrollViewer ViewChanged="ScrollViewer_ViewChanged">
    <ListView x:Name="NewsListView" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewsList, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="NewsInformation" 
                                Padding="5,0,5,0" >
                        <Grid Background="Black" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <!-- there is some row definitions and stack panel with content -->
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="9" 
                                        Height="0.4" 
                                        Background="#f24f00" 
                                        Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="10" 
                                        Padding="0,25" 
                                        Margin="-20,0,-20,0" 
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <ProgressRing x:Name="progressRing"  
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                              Foreground="White" 
                                              Height="30" 
                                              Width="30" 
                                              IsActive="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

and I doesn't work. When I try debug program IsLoading have right value but loading ring is always active. Varible IsLoadig is in my NewsModel. And ViewModel has ObservableCollection. How I can show and hide my loading ring?

Comment: Set `Mode=OneWay` for your binding

Comment: I try it but stil don't work.

Comment: Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: When you bind a list to `ListView` You will receive a list of all items together. So in this case you will see a bunch of Progress Rings even if you manage to fix your problem. Not a good UI Experience. Make your Progress ring separate from ListView and when your list reaches end and when you are loading the next set of ListViewItems, Set `IsActive` Enabled/Disabled based on the activity

Comment: Also you do not need to Wrap Your `ListView` with a `Scrollviewer`. ListView already has a ScrollViewer. So scrolling will work by default.

Comment: Thank you AVK I make progres ring separate from ListView and it works.